# how can i sort the table columns according to datetime in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I added a lot of rows to table. it is sorted by ID However, I want to sort by datetime.

table name's is rss and column's name is rss_date(type: DateTime)

Comment: this should be the simplest of google searches

Comment: Select order by date field, I'm pretty sure you can find it yourself..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ORDER BY` with `ASCENDING` or `DESCENDING`.

If you want to show in ascending order it is not necessary to put `ASC`.  For `DESCENDING`you have to use `DESC` after the column name.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
ORDER BY columnName DESC; -- or ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Umm, you can use the `ORDER BY` clause...

```
SELECT *
FROM rss
ORDER BY rss_date;
```

Comment: how can i order by date which is high

Comment: @leventkalay92 Use `ORDER BY rss_date DESC` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * From rss Order by rss_date ASC;
```

You can use either `ASC` or `DESC`